# Filemaker Pro 12 - Get ( ScriptResult ) from script in another file returning empty

Tags: filemaker

I have a script in file a that calls another script in file b using PerformScript.  I need to get the result of this script, but calling Get( ScriptResult ) does not work, it is always empty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us see the contents of your scripts? It's difficult to say what is happening without the detail.

The script in file b must be exited using the *Exit Script* script step, and that script step must have the result option set.

*Get(ScriptResult)* in the calling script should then return the result.